# Converting a PCRE regular expressions to an expression to be used with std::regex

Tags: c++, regex, pcre

I have the following pcre regular expression to detect sentence boundaries, and I would like to use it in C++ with std::regex.

```
((?<=[a-z0-9][.?!])|(?<=[a-z0-9][.?!]\"))(\s|\r\n)(?=\"?[A-Z])
```

How could I make this work?

Comment: Two things should be cleared out: `std::regex` default flavor is ECMAScript so it supports lookaheads, and it is not limited to POSIX. Second, could you  please provide at least 1 use case? Are you planning to use it in a `regex_replace` method? Also, note that `(\s|\r\n)` must be probably written as `(\r\n|\s)` since `\s` as the first alternative will always "win" and `\r\n` will never be tried. I'd even use `\s+` here instead, to match 1+ whitespaces. If you can post the code you are planning to use the regex with, it would be best.

Comment: If you need fast help please answer the questions in my comment adding these details to the question itself.

Comment: Sorry, don't have any code. The goal is to I have a string such as "Sentence one. Sentence two. Sentence three." and then break the string on each sentence.

Comment: Ok, so you want to split and get a string vector as the result?

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/ow1ppB